# Hacking the Bluetooth motor in the motorized LEGO® DC Super Heroes 76112 App-Controlled Batmobile

Tags: bluetooth, powered-up

I'd like to hack the receiver / motor so I can control it from my Mac (or a PC if there is no other way).

Recently LEGO released an app-controlled Batmobil - product detailed are here: 
https://shop.lego.com/en-US/App-Controlled-Batmobile-76112

The Bluetooth receiver (LEGO Part #6253628) can connect to an app, in our case, an iPhone. I tried to see if it was visible in the Bluetooth elements to connect to, and nope... I cannot also find any MAC address on the receiver itself.

Any hint or clue?

## Edit #1

I am looking for a way to connect to the Bluetooth receiver and be able to program it in **Python** (or C/Java...), but not a GUI.

Comment: I think I read Boost and Power Up have the same protocol, so this might help: https://github.com/JorgePe/BOOSTreveng

Answer (score 7):

There's a node.js library that can connect to the Move Hub and control attached peripherals:

https://github.com/nathankellenicki/node-poweredup

This should allow you to write scripts and programs that can control the motor from your Mac.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for. I have to see if I can connect to the BT this way as my Mac did not see it, which was the first issue. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Good luck! Let us know how it goes.

Comment: If having difficulty connecting, check that you are using  ‘Bluetooth Low Energy’  to connect- if Your Mac isn’t using this protocol, you can get a dongle to use this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out with nRF Connect app -> if you can find it with it, you can read services and characteristics of this lego peripheral and based on that control it. Good luck!